# PhpStorm and gulp.js task. Need to double save to upload compiled CSS

Tags: sass, gulp, phpstorm

Using PhpStorm 10.0 and configured `gulp.js` task to run on startup, also uploading modified files on Ctrl+Save.

When I edit `.scss` and it's compiles to `.css` PhpStorm will not upload compiled .css, I need to double save every time if I want to upload newly compiled .css file.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Try newer PhpStorm version (latest stable is 2016.1.2 .. and EAP is 2016.2); 2) Please show your file watcher settings (screenshot) + tell where the generated/compiled file is located relative to the source file -- next to it .. or in separate folder? That's if you are using file watcher, of course. If you are just using `gulp watch` .. then this behaviour is actually expected as IDE does not check what some background task does.

Comment: Yes I just configured gulp task to run on startup and no file watcher. Not sure how to do it and didn't tried. So I need to watch compiled .css file and on change detected upload it or synchronize with remote server.

Comment: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm 2) With your current `gulp watch` approach such behaviour is absolutely expected because IDE is not aware what *some random background task* does to your project files. Instead of saving file for a second time you may use `File | Synchronize` to re-read project files looking for changes. But if you want automatic uploading -- file watchers is the proper way to go here because it can see when the compilation is done and can check the target file for changes.

Comment: actually PHPStorm should synchronize its file system when Gulp watch is triggered... Do you run your Gulp task from PHPStorm, using Gulp integration, or externally in your OS terminal? In the latter case no auto-sync can be performed, and you have to synchronize the file system manually to get generated files uploaded

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I am running into the same issue. Using understrap and phpStorm, I do get the CSS files made, but they do not get put in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is expected behavior, so there is no fix. CSS compilling after you hit Strl+s so phpstorm don't see changes in CSS yet. I find it better to work localy when possible.